# before/afterAll() is not defined in jasmine-node

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-node, frisby.js, web-api-testing

I'm trying to use the methods **beforeAll** and **afterAll** of jasmine, to create a suite of tests with **frisby.js**, because actually, frisby doesn't have a support for this methods. So, this is what I'm trying to do:

```
var frisby = require('frisby');
describe("setUp and tearDown", function(){
    beforeAll(function(){
        console.log("test beforeAll");
    });

    afterAll(function(){
        console.log("afterAll");
    });

//FRISBY TESTS
}); //end of describe function
```

If I change the methods before/afterAll to before/afterEach, is working, but when I'm using before/afterAll this error appears on console:

> Message:
>        ReferenceError: beforeAll is not defined
>      Stacktrace:
>        ReferenceError: beforeAll is not defined

I have the jasmine version 2.3.2 installed on my project, so, I don't know what I need to do to integrate this method.

Answer (score 2):

Use the jasmine library not the jasmine-node library. The second one does not support beforeAll and afterAll methods.

1- npm install -g jasmine

2- jasmine init

3- write the test in the spec folder:

```
  describe("A spec using beforeAll and afterAll", function() {
    var foo;

    beforeAll(function() {
     foo = 1;
    });

    afterAll(function() {
     foo = 0;
    });

    it("sets the initial value of foo before specs run", function() {
      expect(foo).toEqual(1);
      foo += 1;
    });

   it("does not reset foo between specs", function() {
     expect(foo).toEqual(2);
   });
});
```

4- Run the tests --> jasmine

Comment: But the problem is, I need to use the jasmine-node to execute the frisby.js tests, because im doing tests on an api service..

Comment: Why was this answer voted down. @cesarluis is right, jasmine-node doesn't support these methods.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of frisby doesnt suport this kind of setup. The community, like myself is eager to this feature like in this [issue](https://github.com/vlucas/frisby/issues/91) describes.

The team is working on this feature, but it will come  in version 2 of the package that is in the way for more than a year now. More info at this [link](https://github.com/vlucas/frisby/issues/316).